Help Me Find the Molding
I have a piece of rotten molding between a sliding glass door and a fixed glass panel at its side. The profile of the molding is similar to this one, except that the middle strip is flat and has the same height as the two half-round strip.
The total width is about 1-5/8 inches, and middle strip is about 7/8". If anyone know where to find the molding, please help. Thank you in advance.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We do not do shopping/where to get questions.  A window/door store might be able to help or it is custom made for the door maker.  Is it wood or something else?  If wood, might be able to make it with a router and the right bits.

If the moulding is rotted, replace it with something similar. Why does a new piece need to be exactly like the old piece?

@RMDman, Thanks for comment. I am afraid of causing more damages if I replace the whole piece of molding. Plus, the other side of the door has the same molding, I would like to keep them the same.

I have that around all the outside doors ... check with a door shop

Probably a lot easier to add a plinth moulding block or casing at the bottom of each side than to remove all of the trim and try to match it.    Find a block you like, cut out the height and width (baseboards) and install.    20 mins minus the painting.

Thanks. That's definitely a brilliant idea. Just one thing though, my molding is 3/8 inch thick. Any plinth blocks could be too thick.

Plinths are naturally thicker than the trim they are attached to.   They are made that was so the trim can butt into it.    If however you want the plinth exact depth match then just plane or sand it.

Thanks a lot! I probably just go this way.

I tried plinth block first. If I line it up with the trim behind the molding, the molding would stand at one side of the plinth block, which does not look very good. So, I ended up with making the molding myself by cutting a flat piece, using my table saw to cut two grooves and then sanding it to the shape I needed. The result is not bad by my standard.
